# Automatic target "here" with \bookmark (as with \pdfbookmark)?

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor,bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\lipsum[1-3]

  % hyperref:
  \pdfbookmark[2]{Test Bookmark Sect. 1}{TstBookmark1}
  \lipsum[4-12]

\section{Section 2}

  \lipsum[13-16]

  % bookmark:
  \bookmark[page=\thepage,rellevel=1,keeplevel,view={XYZ},bold,color=blue]{Test Bookmark Sect. 2}
  %
  % bookmark with target:
  \hypertarget{hereSectII}{}% second arg prints text!
  \bookmark[dest=hereSectII,rellevel=1,keeplevel,view={XYZ},bold,color=blue]{Test Bookmark Sect. II}
  %
  \lipsum[17-20]

\section{Section 3}

  Finished.

\end{document}
```

... which generates output like this (*left `evince`, right Adobe Reader*):

[image: evince_reader.png]

As it can be seen, the target location being focused when the "Test Bookmark Sect. 1":

```
\pdfbookmark[2]{Test Bookmark Sect. 1}{TstBookmark1}
```

... is clicked, is between the paragraphs - basically, the target of the bookmark is "here" (so to speak), the location where `\pdfbookmark` was placed in the code.

My question is - is there a similar syntax for `\bookmark`?

If I specify a `page` action, that one links to the top of a page - and otherwise, I have to manually specify a `\hypertarget`:

```
\hypertarget{hereSectII}{}
\bookmark[dest=hereSectII]{Test Bookmark Sect. II}
```

Compared to this, it seems that `\pdfbookmark` inserts both a hypertarget in the document - and the bookmark (which shows in the PDF bookmarks index). Is there a similar syntax for `\bookmark`?

Comment: I'm sure it would be possible to include a key-value option for `\bookmark` that would place a `\hypertarget` and then also set the `\bookmark` `dest` value. Is this what you're after?

Comment: Hi @Werner - yes; I was wandering if there is an "official" way to do something like that, so I can type both the target name and the bookmark command on one line (of course, I could always try to build my own macro for that - but I was wandering if there is something "officially" in the `bookmark` package for this). Thanks!

Comment: A quick view only shows `dest`, for which you need a location (or a target... `\hypertarget`). `rawaction` is not suggested according to the [`bookmark` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/bookmark.pdf) while `page` is page-specific and so seems `named`. So I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @Werner - would you mind posting your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau is that the page numbers that we see in the bookmarks in Evince on the right side? Is this the default behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

The [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) redefines `\pdfbookmark` as a compatibility-feature to [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref):

```
\let\pdfbookmark\ltx@undefined
\newcommand*{\pdfbookmark}[3][0]{%
  \bookmark[level=#1,dest={#3.#1}]{#2}%
  \hyper@anchorstart{#3.#1}\hyper@anchorend
}
```

In essence, `\pdfbookmark` uses `\bookmark` with a specific `dest` key-value, and places both a `\hyper@anchorstart` and `\hyper@anchorend` to match that.

The following MWE provides a similar interface as an extension to `\bookmark` that now takes an optional `*`. When you use `\bookmark[<options>]{<text>}`, things work as before. However, `\bookmark*[<options>]{<text>}` overrides any use of `dest` in `<options>` in inserts an automated (and incremental) destination:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{hyperref,bookmark}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xcolor,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{@bookmark@cntr}
\renewcommand{\the@bookmark@cntr}{autobookmark-\arabic{@bookmark@cntr}}
\let\@bookmark\bookmark
\renewcommand{\bookmark}{%
  \@ifstar\@bookmark@star\@bookmark
}
\newcommand{\@bookmark@star}[2][]{%
  \stepcounter{@bookmark@cntr}%
  \@bookmark[#1,dest=\the@bookmark@cntr]{#2}%
  \hyper@anchorstart{\the@bookmark@cntr}\hyper@anchorend%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\lipsum[1-3]

% hyperref:
\pdfbookmark[2]{Test Bookmark Sect. 1}{TstBookmark1}
\lipsum[4-12]

\section{Section 2}

\lipsum[13-16]

% bookmark:
\bookmark[page=\thepage,rellevel=1,keeplevel,view={XYZ},bold,color=blue]{Test Bookmark Sect. 2}
%
% bookmark with target:
\hypertarget{hereSectII}{}% second arg prints text!
\bookmark[dest=hereSectII,rellevel=1,keeplevel,view={XYZ},bold,color=blue]{Test Bookmark Sect. II}
%
\lipsum[17-20]

\section{Section 3}

% Updated \bookmark* usage.
\bookmark*[rellevel=1,keeplevel,view={XYZ},bold,color=blue]{Test Bookmark Sect. 3}

\lipsum[21-30]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a direct interface for this, but you can provide your own boolean key `desthere` say and use `\phantomsection`. (Note however that I have never used `kvsetkeys` and so am not convinced that this is the best way to define the key.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor,bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\define@key{BKM}{desthere}[true]{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname if#1\endcsname\iftrue
        \phantomsection
        \bookmarksetupnext{dest=\@currentHref}
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\lipsum[1-3]

  \bookmark[desthere,rellevel=1,keeplevel,view={XYZ},bold,color=blue]{Test Bookmark Sect. I}

  \lipsum[4-12]

\end{document}
```

Note also that the `bookmark` package changes `\pdfbookmark` to use the `\bookmark` macro, but it does not provide any direct way to add options. However, `\bookmarksetupnext` can be used there too:

```
\bookmarksetupnext{bold,color=blue}
\pdfbookmark[2]{Test Bookmark Sect. 1}{TstBookmark1}
```